# how to use another-model in a controller?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

i want to use another model in a controller for example in users_controller.php,we use a model as User how i can use another model for example sports_controller model as Sport?

Comment: *(reference)* [Cake Book: Understanding Models](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1001/Understanding-Models) - though it should be noted that the Cake definition of Model only applies to Cake's ecosystem. In general, the Model is not just the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$this -> loadModel ('Sports');
```

Then you can use it like any other model:

```
$this -> Sports -> find ('all');
```

Comment: my another friend says it could be like this$this->User->Sports->find('all');

Comment: But What could be the difference?

Comment: @Zaars If your friend claims to know it better, then ask your friend how to do it.

Comment: i like your refrence! thanx gordan!both ways are good $this -> loadModel ('Sports');
AND $this->User->Sports->find('all');

Comment: @Zaarsbrothers you can reference the sports model this way if the User model is attached through any of Cake's relationships.  So, if a user hasMany Sports in the User class, then in the controller you can use the Sports model like your example without including it in the $uses parameter.